# lucene - search in list of objects

Tags: hibernate, jpa, lucene, hibernate-search

I have the entity `ExerciseEntity` which contains a list of objects `identifiers`

```
@ElementCollection
@IndexedEmbedded(targetElement = IdentifierEntity.class)
private Set<IdentifierEntity> identifiers;
```

Example of the list:

```
"identifiers": [
    {
      "identifierType": "AM",
      "identifierValue": "333333333"
    },
    {
      "identifierType": "FINESS",
      "identifierValue": "888888888"
    }
]
```

the attribut `identifierType` is of type enum, so i implemented a custom bridge like in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62300140/4739210) .

```
@Enumerated
@Field(name = "identifierType", bridge = @FieldBridge(impl = EnumAsIntegerBridge.class))
private IdentifierTypeEnum identifierType;
```

I want to search all `ExerciseEntity` by `identifierValue` which `identifierType` equals FINESS.
I tried with the below query, but it doesn't work correctly, when i test with identifierValue=333333333, i get a result, but i should get nothing because its type is AM not FINESS.

```
List<Query> listOfQuery = new ArrayList<>();
listOfQuery.add(getQueryBuilder().keyword().onField("identifiers.identifierType").matching(IdentifierTypeEnum.FINESS.ordinal()).createQuery());
listOfQuery.add(getQueryBuilder().keyword().onField("identifiers.identifierValue").matching(identifierValue).createQuery());
Builder finalLuceneQuery = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
listOfQuery.stream().forEach(query -> finalLuceneQuery.add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));

FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = getFullTextEntityManager().createFullTextQuery(finalLuceneQuery.build(), ExerciseEntity.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions. [Upgrading](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/migration/html_single/) to [Hibernate Search 6.0](https://hibernate.org/search/releases/6.0/) or later is mandatory for the first solution only, but I'd recommend upgrading anyway, because Hibernate Search 5.x is no longer getting new features.

### Solution 1: nested documents

I'll show how to do this with Hibernate Search 6.x, because there is no equivalent in Hibernate Search 5.x.

In Hibernate Search 6+, you can [mark your `@IndexedEmbedded` as `NESTED`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-indexedembedded-structure).

```java
@ElementCollection
@IndexedEmbedded(structure = ObjectStructure.NESTED)
private Set<IdentifierEntity> identifiers;
```

Then the structure of your `IdentifierEntity` objects will be preserved in the index, and you'll be able to specify during search that you want two predicates to apply to the same object by wrapping them in a `nested` predicate:

```java
List<ExerciseEntity> hits = searchSession.search( ExerciseEntity.class )
        .where( f -> f.nested().objectField( "identifiers" ) 
                .nest( f.bool()
                        .must( f.match().field( "identifiers.identifierType" )
                                .matching( IdentifierTypeEnum.FINESS ) ) 
                        .must( f.match().field( "identifiers.identifierValue" )
                                .matching( identifierValue ) ) 
                ) )
        .fetchHits( 20 );
```

### Solution 2: single field for both values

There's a hack to replicate the behavior above without using nested documents: just merge the two fields into one.

I'll show how to do this with Hibernate Search 5.x, since you seem to be using that, but the same solution can perfectly well be implemented with Hibernate Search 6.x (with a [value bridge](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#_stringbridge)).

Implement a custom bridge that does exactly that:

```java
public class IdentifierAsStringBridge implements MetadataProvidingFieldBridge, StringBridge {
    public static String toString(IdentifierTypeEnum type, String value) {
        return type.name() + ":" + value;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureFieldMetadata(String name, FieldMetadataBuilder builder) {
        builder.field( name, FieldType.String );
    }

    @Override
    public void set(String name, Object value, Document document, LuceneOptions luceneOptions) {
        if ( value == null ) {
            return;
        }

        Collection<IdentifierEntity> idCollection = (Collection<IdentifierEntity>) value;

        for ( IdentifierEntity id : idCollection ) {
            luceneOptions.addFieldToDocument( name, toString( id.getIdentifierType(), id.getIdentifierValue() ), document );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String objectToString(Object value) {
        if ( value instanceof String ) {
            return (String) value;
        }
        else if ( value instanceof IdentifierEntity ) {
            IdentifierEntity id = (IdentifierEntity) value;
            return toString( id.getIdentifierType(), id.getIdentifierValue() );
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "This bridge only supports passing arguments of type String or IdentifierEntity" );
        }
    }

}
```

Use that new bridge on your "identifiers" collection:

```java
@ElementCollection
@Field(name = "identifiers_strings", bridge = @FieldBridge(impl = IdentifierAsStringBridge.class))
private Set<IdentifierEntity> identifiers;
```

And finally, update your query to target the single field you just added:

```java
List<Query> listOfQuery = new ArrayList<>();
listOfQuery.add(getQueryBuilder().keyword()
        .onField("identifiers_strings")
        .matching(IdentifierAsStringBridge.toString(
                IdentifierTypeEnum.FINESS, identifierValue
        ))
        .createQuery());

Builder finalLuceneQuery = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
listOfQuery.stream().forEach(query -> finalLuceneQuery.add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));

FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = getFullTextEntityManager()
        .createFullTextQuery(finalLuceneQuery.build(), ExerciseEntity.class);
```

Comment: thnx for your reply ^^ 
When i follow the solution 2, i get this error `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet cannot be cast to IdentifierEntity`, to resolve it i update the `set` method
`public void set(String name, Object value, Document document, LuceneOptions luceneOptions) {
  Set<IdentifierEntity> ids = (Set<IdentifierEntity>) value;

  if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(ids)) {
   for(IdentifierEntity id: ids) {
    luceneOptions.addFieldToDocument(name, toString(id.getIdentifierType(), id.getIdentifierValue()), document);
   }
  }
 }`

Comment: i get this new error `org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000169: FieldBridge 'IdentifierAsStringBridge' does not have a objectToString method: field 'identifiers_strings' in 'ExerciseEntity' The FieldBridge must be a TwoWayFieldBridge or you have to enable the ignoreFieldBridge option when defining a Query`

Comment: I updated my answer, in particular the code of the bridge.